# Meaning of the _/ icon on SmartGit log

Tags: smartgit

In the following screen capture from SmartGit, what is the meaning on the little "_/" icon before a commit message? It seems to imply a reddish date to the right, too.

[image: Screen capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon indicates that the commit is signed. The **Commit** view will indicate **Signed** here, too.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had checked for differences on the commit view, but I had overlooked this.